# Start \partpage on an even-numbered page

Tags: beamer

Given the following Beamer presentation, how can I force (pdf)LaTeX to put the \partpage on an even-numbered page? I initially thought that [Finding if you’re on an odd or an even page](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-oddpage) might be a good starting point but to no avail:

```
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\frame{intentionally left blank}
\frame{\partpage}
\else
\frame{\partpage}
\fi
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%% Show page number 
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
  \usebeamerfont{footline}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \vspace{0.5em}%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\begin{document}

\part{Part 1}
\frame{\partpage}

\frame{1.1}

\part{Part 2}
\frame{\partpage}

\frame{2.1}

\part{Part 3}
\frame{\partpage}

\frame{3.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what "even numbered page" means in a presentation?

Comment: @egreg Well, I mean pages 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...

Comment: I can't see what you mean: there are no “pages” in a presentation. Frames have a number, but what would an empty frame do in a presentation?

Comment: The presentation is going to be distributed as hard copy and I was asked to start each \part on an "even-numbered page/frame".

Comment: The thing is, `beamer` is designed for screens (unless you use `article` mode). So, for example, the page sizes are non-standard for printing. If the 'presentation' is to be distributed in hard copy, maybe it would be best to use another class or to use the `article` mode? I'm finding it difficult to imagine just how this is supposed to work, actually. How is what you are trying to do different from distributing a handout?

Comment: @cfr Yes, I want to distribute a handout. The slides will be printed double-sided and it would be nice if parts could start on an even-numbered page (i.e. on the right-hand side; the title page does not count).

Comment: So the `beamer` class is probably not the best option here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `\ifthenelse{condition}{one command}{another command}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen,catchfile,forloop}

%% Show page number 
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
  \usebeamerfont{footline}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
  \vspace{0.5em}%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{
    \part{#1}
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\arabic{framenumber}}}{ \frame{\partpage} }{ \frame{intentionally left blank} \frame{\partpage} }
}

\begin{document}

\mypart{test 1}
\frame{1.1}

\mypart{test 2}
\frame{2.1}
\frame{2.2}

\mypart{test 3}
\frame{3.1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks very much!